# How do I handle height of my one section in @media print, where page size is A4 and I want to get full page height to the section after page break

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

"So, here is my issue: I am trying to create CVs with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I am using the CSS grid system to design them. I want the left section to still have full height of **`window.innerHeight`** when there is no data in the right section. Additionally, I am using the A4 page size, and I want to ensure that if the content breaks across pages, the logic should make sure that even if there's little data, the left section stretches to the end of the page."
And I want full height in print view after page breakage, `Ctrl + p`

I tried something like this ,

```
  <script>
    // Function to set background color based on content height
    function setColorBasedOnContentHeight() {
      const content = document.querySelector('.content');
      const body = document.body;
      const left = document.querySelector('.leftScection');

      if (content.clientHeight < window.innerHeight) {
        left.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'; // Color for the remaining area
      } else {
        left.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // Original color
      }
    }

    // Initial call to set the color based on content height
    setColorBasedOnContentHeight();

    // Update color when the window is resized
    window.addEventListener('resize', setColorBasedOnContentHeight);
  </script>
```

but this is not working ,

This is my `HTML`

```
 <div class="containter outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="row gx-0">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-xl-4 gx-0">
          <div id="image-js" class="image text-center"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-section col-8 col-sm-8 col-xl-8">
          <div class="inner-right">
            <div class="name-container">
              <div
                id="name-js"
                class="name d-flex flex-column align-items-start justify-content-center"
                style="margin: 2.5vw 2.5vw 2.5vw 0"
              ></div>
              <!--.name-->
            </div>
            <!--.name-container-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row gx-0">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-xl-4 gx-0 left-section" > 
          <div class=" left-inner text-light">
            <!--.image-->
            <div
              class="d-flex align-items-center margin-class"
              style="
                border-bottom: 0.1vw solid #bbbdbf;
                column-gap: 1vw;
                padding-bottom: 0.5vw;
              "
            >
              <div id="icon-contact"></div>
              <div id="cont-js" class="contact"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="phone-js" class="phone lang margin-class"></div>

            <!--.phone-->

            <div id="email-js" class="email lang margin-class"></div>

            <!--.email-->

            <div id="website-js" class="website lang margin-class"></div>

            <!--.website-->

            <div id="address-js" class="address lang margin-class"></div>

            <!-- Address -->

            <div id="lang-js" class="languages margin-class"></div>

            <!--#lang-js-->
            <div id="sk-js" class="ss margin-class"></div>
            <!--#sk-js-->
            <div id="int-js" class="interests margin-class"></div>
            <!--#int-js-->
            <div id="certs-js" class="certificate margin-class"></div>
            <!-- #certs-js -->
            <div id="social-js" class="social margin-class"></div>
            <!--#social-js-->
          </div>
          <!--.left-inner-->
        </div>
        <!--.left-seciton-->
        <div class="right-section col-8 col-sm-8 col-xl-8">
          <div class="inner-right">
            <div
              id="about-js"
              class="about section cv-section page-break"
            ></div>
            <!-- .about -->
            <div
              id="exp-js"
              class="experience section cv-section page-break"
            ></div>
            <!-- .experience -->
            <div id="edu-js" class="education page-break"></div>
            <!--.education-->
            <div
              id="proj-js"
              class="experience section cv-section page-break"
            ></div>
            <!-- #proj-js -->
            <div
              id="pubs-js"
              class="experience section cv-section page-break"
            ></div>
            <!-- #pubs-js -->
            <div
              id="ref-js"
              class="experience section cv-section page-break"
            ></div>
            <!--#ref-js-->

            <div
              id="skill-title-js"
              class="skills experience section cv-section page-break"
            ></div>
            <!-- #skill-title-js -->
          </div>
          <!--.inner-right-->
        </div>
        <!--.right-section-->
      </div>
      <!--.row-->
    </div>
    <!--.inner-container-->
  </div>
```

And this is my `CSS`

```
<style>
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;400;700&family=Lato:wght@100;400;700&family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@100;400;700&family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&family=Roboto:wght@100;400;700&family=Rubik:wght@300;400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap");

    :root {
        --primary-color: #3f63ef;
        --primary-shade: #f6f6f6;
        --levels-grey: #cbcbcb;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: Inter;
        src: url(fonts/Inter/Inter-VariableFont_slnt\wght.ttf);
        font-weight: 400;
    }


    h1 {
        font-size: 1.1vw;
        letter-spacing: 0.1vw;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    p {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 0.3vw;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    /*
    |==========================|
    |=======Left Section=======|
    |==========================|
*/

    .left-section {
        background-color: #1b594d;
        padding: 2vw 0vw;
        border-radius: 0px 2vw 0px 0px;
    }

    .image {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 2vw;
    }

    .image .shadow {
        border-radius: 50%;

        border: 2px solid white;
        padding: 1vw;
    }

    .image img {
        width: 10vw;
        height: 10vw;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .languages,
    .ss,
    .interests,
    .certificate,
    .social,
    .phone,
    .phon,
    .email,
    .emai,
    .web,
    .add,
    .website,
    .address {
        word-break: break-all;
    }

    .lang {
        margin: 1.4vw 1.4vw 1.4vw 0;
    }

    .icons-div {
        width: 2.5vw;
        height: 2.5vw;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0.5vw;
    }

    .icons {
        width: 2vw;
        height: 2vw;
    }

    .icons-div-right {
        width: 2.5vw;
        height: 2.5vw;
        background-color: #1b594d;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0.5vw;
    }

    .contact h1 {
        font-size: 1.1vw;
        font-family: Inter;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .inner-right {
        padding: 3vw 2vw;
    }

    /* lolipop */

    .pop {
        position: absolute;
        height: 1vw;
        width: 1vw;
        border-radius: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .stick {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0.1vw;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .education {
        margin-top: 2vw;
    }

    .experience {
        margin-top: 2vw;
    }

    .margin-class {
        margin-left: 4vw;
    }

    .name h1 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.1vw !important;
        letter-spacing: 0.2vw;
    }

    @media print {
        @page {
            size: A4;
            max-height: 100vh;
            margin-top: 5vw;
        }

        .page-break {
            page-break-after: auto;
        }
    }
</style>
```